# How bad it is to have the warning 'Can only update a mounted or mounting component' in React native?

Tags: react-native

I have this warning but I didn't come here to ask for what it means. I know the warning. What I want to know is if is bad to put in production the app with this warnings. For example, in the code I do a 'dirty trick' to reach a thing I have to do. It only can be done forcing to switch 2 screens without giving time to charge things and due to it, it throwing this warning. But it does not matter me, it does not make the app go slower o something like. But facing with uploading this app to the App Store or Google Play with this warning could give me problems? I've never upload an app yet. Thanks to the help.

Answer (score 1):

Warnings are ignored in production. They are disabled. And for a trivial one like this, there is no performance penalty. So, there is nothing to worry about.

Comment: @Mtg Kha Jeskai Try it with building the app with production flavor. See react-native docs how. This should create a js bundle which will work independently and should not display any warnings and errors during runtime.